# 2 CSVs same Columns but with additional entries - need all the date together

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 CSV files with the same column name e.g.

| CUSTOMER ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

total rows 200
The second CSV has duplicate entries within this column,

| CUSTOMER ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 |
| 3 | 02/01/2020 |
| 3 | 02/01/2020 |

total rows 3000 (due to multiple entries)

In consecutive rows - I need the CUSTOMER ID and the DATE columns with all the dates in the 1st CSV - how do I get this date in 1 place? TIA

I tried all sorts, but can't seem to find an answer - HELP!

Comment: Please , Provide example of (csv format) for first and second csv, and also the expected output

Comment: As it's written you want to combine the first table into the second, so the date column for those entries will be blank? You could use a power query to combine these two tables then sort so the customer IDs are together.

Comment: Hi , for the sample input you provided, please edit the question and show us what you need the output to look like. Also, please include your attempts so far. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a `groupby` question, but since the question is not clear, it is hard to answer.